# Problem with chunks being truncated when receiving data by Streaming

Tags: node.js, streaming, openai-api

I call another api from my server (GPT from OPENAI for example).

When I apply streaming at that time, it should come like data : { } ... but sometimes it doesn't start with data : and starts from the middle of the previous chunk. It should be chunked based on \n\n, but it comes truncated on some weird basis.

Where is the part I should be looking at?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.  Regular streaming in nodejs is not chunked by any particular boundary.  That's up to a layer you add on top of the streaming.  So, unless you're using some additional layer on top of regular nodejs streaming, you will have to manually collect data, find a whole chunk up to your `\n\n` terminator and then process that piece yourself.